# How to implement DownloadManager in Java Web Application?

Tags: java, download-manager

We're planning a module in our web application built on Java EE 6 features (Ejb 3.1, JSF 2.0, JPA w/ Hibernate 2.0) that comprehends something like a 'download manager'/'upload manager' module.

The user of this web application should be able to obtain files by downloading them, however due to limited connectivity, he/she must be able to stop the download, exit the application, and when logged again, resume previous download(s). The same thing must be possible for uploads.

I have no much experience on that but customer has put some restrictions on us:

1. He will deny any solution that consists in a new subapplication to be installed (like Java Web Start, things like that).
2. He doesn't want to buy any certificates in case of Java Applets.

So, anyone whoever has made something like that, how could I perform that using only server-side Java EE programming? Which would be the best suitable for this case?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this tutorial from BalusC very helpful [FileServlet Supporting Resume And Caching](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html)

Comment: Surely it`s very helpful. Tyvm.

Comment: if you think something was helpful a vote or accept would work, just some info for new users. :-)